# ThreadingUnixStreamServer socket cleanup after KeyboardInterrupt?

Tags: python, socketserver, keyboardinterrupt

I am puzzled by the socketserver module behaviour upon exit, especially regarding unix socket creation and cleanup.

From the code below, and the documentation, i wonder if **not** removing the unix socket *is* the normal behaviour, or if i missed something and my program flow *prevents* the cleanup from happening.

Here is my simple code using python 3.9.2 :

```py
import os
from socketserver import ThreadingUnixStreamServer, StreamRequestHandler


class MyStreamRequestHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # dummy action
        for raw_line in self.rfile:
            print(raw_line)


SOCK = '/tmp/foo.sock'
server = ThreadingUnixStreamServer(SOCK, MyStreamRequestHandler)
try:
    # edit: using a "with server:" results in the same behaviour
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Interrupted by user")
finally:
    # here i see that the socket is still present
    os.system(f"ls -l {SOCK}")
    # so i remove it manually because i would get an
    # 'OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use'
    # on the next script run
    try:
        os.remove(SOCK)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        pass
```

I expected that the server would cleanup the socket it created, upon exit or interruption.